# Is there a Windows 10 setting or an app that can control a laptop's battery charge capacity?

Tags: battery, battery-life

There is a bundled laptop software that comes with a battery master that allows users to set the maximum limit of the battery charge capacity (e.g. 60%, 80%, 100%). Is there a Windows 10 application or setting that could do the same thing?

Here is a visual:
[image: battery charge capacity control]

Comment: this setting is not maximum - it is minimum, the percentage BEFORE the charger will start to charge the battery.

Comment: @Zina Actually it's both minimum and maximum. The hysteresis window is always 10% wide.

Comment: yep :) thanks @gronostaj - was reading before I finished my first coffee...

Comment: [How to Adjust the Reserve Battery Level on a Windows 10 Laptop](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/adjust-reserve-battery-level-in-windows-10-for-better-performance/#:~:text=The%20classic%20Control%20Panel%20will,percentage%20to%20what%20you%20want.)

Answer (score 4):

Windows does not have a setting for maximum charge. It is up to the manufacturer
of the laptop to supply such a utility, and there are also some third-party products.

Below is a small list:

- For an ASUS laptop see
  [ASUS Battery Health Charging](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1032726/)
- For a Lenovo laptop see
  [Lenovo Vantage](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/solutions/ht505081)
- [Battery Limiter](https://www.robotonfire.com/bl/)
  is a freeware application for setting the charging limit on the laptop.

Comment: Update: ASUS has this feature in an application they call "MyASUS" which you will have to install in order to change the battery charge limit (for ASUS laptops).

Answer (score 1):

**No.** It's a custom feature created by laptop's manufacturer and it can't be managed by the OS itself. You can change it only with software provided by the manufacturer and maybe a BIOS setting.

Answer (score 0):

For Dell it is possible to set start charging at for example 50%. And stop att 70%.

More settings possible. With:

Dell Power Manager

https://www.dell.com/support/contents/sv-se/article/product-support/self-support-knowledgebase/software-and-downloads/dell-power-manager

[image]